# Entity Framework 6: target two different database systems from one application

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have an application that needs access to two databases. One is SQL Server and the other one is DB2. We found out that we can change the database provider by creating a custom configuration e.g. for DB2:

```
public class DB2DBConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public DB2DBConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderServices(
            DB2ProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName,
            DB2ProviderServices.Instance);
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new DB2ConnectionFactory());
    }
}

internal class DB2ConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString) => new DB2Connection(nameOrConnectionString);
}
```

And then we add the corresponding attribute on top of the model:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(SQLServerDBConfiguration))]
public partial class ProductDBModel : DbContext
```

This works just fine when using only one model with one database. However if we want to use DB2 and SQL Server at the same time (two different DB Models with the specific DbConfigurationType) we get the following error for the second one:

> An instance of "SQLServerDBConfiguration" can not be set as there is already an instance of "DB2DBConfiguration" in use.

What can we do about this issue? How can we target two different database systems in one application with Entity Framework?